# Way to execute a website click activity in background android application

Tags: android, selenium, web, response, htmlunit

I am working on developing an app which involves clicking a tab/div in a website. Click event involves execution of java script in background and server also updates the page with response.

Now, my android app can make use of response data and do its application code. Here, I dont want user to click the tab/div in website. I want this to be done in background and I want the response from the website as input for my app. ) i.e I wish to perform click event on website when user opens the android application.

I have tried this using HtmlUnit and Selenium. Is there any other way to solve this problem ? Please share your valuable answers.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use Selenium for this at all.

Open that website up on a computer and use  Fiddler2 to capture the traffic (there most certainly will be a request somewhere that will trigger that response) and just send the request to the server, receive response, and profit.

If you REALLY want to use selenium inside an android app, you might have better luck with Appium.

Comment: Hi Aholt, Thank you for your valuable response. Creating that request is a bit complicated in my case. I will try my luck with Appium.